# Dynamically loaded images and adding ID attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

[image]I am dynamically load images between each unordered list tag. I would now like to add a unique id to each of the images dynamically loaded. I believe the problem is jQuery is unable to iterate through the images because the images are dynamically loaded? So I tried to iterate through the unordered list tags and then place the generated index (i) number as the corresponding images ID but that is not working either.

jQuery:

```
var img = $("<img />"), li = $('li');

li.append(img);

li.each(function(i){
    img
    .attr( "id", i )
    .attr("src", "img/" + i + ".png")
    .attr("alt", "image" + i);
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><!--<img id="01" src="img/01.png" alt="image01/>--></li>
<li><!--<img id="02" src="img/02.png" alt="image02"/>--></li> 
<li><!--<img id="03" src="img/03.png" alt="image03"/>--></li> 
<li><!--<img id="04" src="img/04.png" alt="image04"/>--></li> 
....
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What is happening is jquery is only outputting image img/12.png not images 1 through 12.png for each li. I will post a screen shot of the problem above.  http://jsfiddle.net/jbryant/F6z7R/

Comment: What's the goal here? Are you looking to turn the images in the comments into live images? I'm confused by your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code:

```
var li = $('ul li');
li.each(function (i) {
    var img = $("<img />");
    img.attr({
        "id": i,
        "src": "img/" + i + ".png",
        "alt": "image" + i,
    });
    $(this).append(img);
});
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/150/

You can pass complete attributes all at once also instead of passing individually.